# An integer variable gets converted to float when introducing it into a dataframe. How keep it as integer?

Tags: python, dataframe, types

I have an integer variable "Sector" and it gets converted to float when introduced into a pandas dataframe, but I want to keep it as integer. Not sure why is happening. I am working in a jupyter notebook.

The code:

```
sector=0
last_sector=1
for sector in range(last_sector,83):
    try:
        address = 'Singapore'+', '+str(sector)
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="to_explorer")
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        print('The geographical coordinates for {} are {}, {}.'.format(address,latitude, longitude))
        sg_sectors = sg_sectors.append({'Sector': sector,
                                        'Latitude': latitude,
                                        'Longitude': longitude}, ignore_index=True)
    except:
        last_sector=int(sg_sectors['Sector'].max())
        print('Coordinates for sectors up to ',last_sector,' have already been gathered')
```

The output is:

```
 Sector   Latitude  Longitude
```

0     1.0     1.339782  103.973006  
1     2.0     1.386609  103.851935  
2     3.0     1.276690  103.869153  
...

[image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63tEO.png)

How can I keep it as integer?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this line, which is a `pandas` antipattern:

```py
sg_sectors = sg_sectors.append({'Sector': sector,
                                'Latitude': latitude,
                                'Longitude': longitude}, ignore_index=True)
```

You are creating a *new* `DataFrame` every iteration. This probably won't matter in this specific case because your dataset is relatively small, but if you scale up, it will. A lot.

This also has the unfortunate side effect of widening the types used to the narrowest common supertype, which is, in this case, `float`. In other words, `sector` is originally an `int`, but because `latitude` and `longitude` are `floats`, `sector` is itself widened to a `float`.

If you want to avoid this, instead collect your values in a `list` by defining, say, `sg_sector_data = []` at the start. Then, in the loop, you can have this:

```py
sector_data = {'Sector': sector, 'Latitude': latitude, 'Longitude': longitude}

sg_sector_data.append(sector_data)
```

And finally, at the end, create your `DataFrame` with `sg_sectors = pd.DataFrame(sg_sector_data)`.

Comment: Good point regarding the alternative of creating and empty list before the loop. I have still 2 questions: 1: What do you mean by "antipattern"? and 2: Why would there be a dataframe created in every iteration? I didn't try the example, but either I would expect, that you raise an error because you append something to a non-existing dataframe, or it is created in the first iteration and in the following you're appending as intended. Can you tell me, where my guess is wrong?

Comment: @Lepakk An "antipattern" is a way of doing things that is generally considered non-idiomatic and/or inefficient and/or misleading.

`append` for a Python `list` modifies it inplace. `append` for a `pd.DataFrame` *creates a copy*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. Indeed my size of the date I am working with is small. I ended up modifying the type of the column after creating the df. But I need to work now in a larger dataset, so will work the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can make columns to be a certain data type by applying astype.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5), columns=['a'])
df.a = df.a.astype(float)
print(df)
     a
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
df = df.astype({'a':int})
print(df)
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

You can apply this datatype to all columns as I did in the first, creating a float dataframe, but also limit the effect to certain columns, using a dictionary as I did to make the column an integer again.

Hope, that helps. Best, lepakk